DeWalt DWS774 mitre saw failure
I have this saw, few years old, but barely any use. I did a couple of cuts, then on a subsequent one the motor wouldn't run, and the shadow line light just flashed as a constant rhythm, every few seconds.
Any experience.of this at all, and if so, how economically repairable do you think it is?

that depends on what is the problem ... asking for opinions is off topic here ... this site is not a forum

Test the capacitor with a multi meter.  They are usually easy and cheap enough to replace and are a main reason for motors not turning/running.

It's a universal/brushed type motor, so that's going to be really hard to replace or test, as there isn't one, @crip659

Ah. What on earth can it be? Failed power supply? Dodgy switch? The XPS light flashing is the really weird thing that I can't grasp

Could the XPS light flashing be a diagnosing signal that a troubleshooting table in the saw's instruction manual might define?

Also, try investigating the motor brushes. Though the saw is low-usage yet, there could have been a manufacturing defect.

@Triplefault possibly. There nothing in the manualz though, and DeWalt refuse to help me diagnose on the phone. Service center is the only choice. Might crack open the motor housing tomorrow and check brushes too.
